# What improvement was made in Su-35 over Su-30?

Tags: aircraft-design, military, fighter, su-27, su-30

What improvement was made in Su-35 over Su-30?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what you are asking.  What does "special" mean?  Why are you trying to compare 2 different aircraft?

Comment: I don't understand what is unclear about this question, especially after the edit.

Comment: @fooot I agree now, but the original question was  far from clear.

Comment: @fooot I voted to close as too broad, not unclear. and I still feel is too broad as it is now.

Answer (score 2):

The Su-30 is an modifications of the SU-27UB
The Su-35 is an Su-27 shaped aircraft with many new parts from the Su-34 (T-10BM)
in detail
Radar N035 Irbis-E PESA
Rear-looking self-defense radar
new fly-by-wire flight-control system
new fully-glass cockpit
Electronic-warfare self-defense system L175M Khibiny-M
Engine AL-37FU/ 117S
larger Air Intakes, no canards, reduced-area empennage

Su-35 has been also called early export versions of the Su-27
and to make more confusion, the production factories (Irkut / Amur) does not name their product Su-35

Please take a look at   http://www.sukhoi.org/eng/planes/military/Su-35/
and   https://defence.pk/pdf/threads/su-30mki-vs-su-35s.222304/

Comment: First link gives a 404, could you fix it ? (I couldn't)